# IE (10) how to remove dotted outline of input element

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

IE (10) Is it possible to remove dotted outline of input element?

[image: dotted outline in IE10]

Comment: `outline: none;` doesn't work?

Comment: Yeah thanks, need to override bootstrap's settings with !important or inline.

Comment: +1 `!important` I was missing this too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE does not draw an outline for `input` elements by default. So you need to find out what in your style sheets causes it and remove or override the relevant setting. For an override, you can use

```
input { outline-style: none }
```

But depending on the style sheet that causes the problem, you may need to make the selector more specific and/or add `!important`.